# Intellisense not showing python docstrings from custom modules?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a virtual environment set up containing stubs for Maya's PyMel module in the virtual environment's /lib/site-packages directory. With this setup, VSCode's Intellisense shows function signatures, but not docstrings:

[image: No docstring with language server]

If I turn on Jedi, the docstring shows up, but it's unbearably slow:

[image: Docstring with jedi]

The docstring does show up without Jedi if I move the module to my local project's directory. But this is a bad solution, as it means I'd have to copy the module (and every other common module) to every project.

Is this behavior intentional? Is there some way to get around it and "force" the language server to show docstrings?

(This is with vscode 1.28.2 and python extension 2018.9.1, Win 7)

Comment: When you say "stubs" do you mean `.pyi` files? Docstrings should be showing (and show for me for a simple example), so chances are either it's a bug or you mean `.pyi` files and they are not having their docstrings set up to come through if the source isn't present.

Comment: They are actually .py files with docstrings but no functional code (e.g., methods are all defined as "pass").  However, the problem applies to fully-defined functions, too, like setuptools.archive_util.unpack_archive(), which comes bundled with every standard installation.

[Edit] I realized that the issue applies to my 2.7 virtual environments, but not my 3.7 virtual environments.  Logged an issue here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2989, but it sounds like Don may not be able to reproduce it...